# How to decide which Area2D is behind?

Tags: 2d, godot

How to make an Area2D drawn after another one only in certain situations?

---

### The boat

```
+ Area2D
|_ AnimatedSprite
```

### The stone

```
+ Area2D
|_ AnimatedSprite
```

---

### Correct

[image]

### Not correct

[image]

Do I have to use 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, you are going to need to put your nodes inside a [`YSort`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_ysort.html) node. And make sure it is enabled. The `YSort` node will sort the sprites by their vertical position (y-axis).

Second set the [`offset`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_sprite.html#class-sprite-property-offset) attribute of each `Sprite`. This attributes allows you to move the texture. What you want is to set it such that the origin point of the `Sprite` is along what should be "ground level" visually on the texture if that makes sense…

Here, visually:

[image: -]

The texture has been moved such that the origin of the `Sprite` goes where the "ground level" of the image would be, visually. *If that is a problem, you can compensate the offset with the position of the `Sprite` inside the `Area2D`. Also make sure the `CollisionShape` makes sense.*

With that setup, it should work automatically. *This could also be done manually by setting `Z Index`.*

[image: Demo]

Comment: I was planning to create a solution like this one, but of course this is an old problem. Many thanks for the complete video tutorial.